# FIFO overflow - reading IMU MPU6090 and GPS uBlox NEO-6M at once

Tags: arduino-uno, gps, mpu6050

I am trying to read data from uBlox NEO-6m (I need just speed, just part of the code):

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

static const int RXPin = 7, TXPin = 4;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

float gps_speed = 0;

// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

void setup(){
ss.begin(GPSBaud);
}

void loop(){
if (ss.available())
    {
      gps.encode(ss.read());
      gps_speed = gps.speed.kmph();

    }
}
```

And in the same time I read data from MPU6090 using this code (gps code is integrated in it):

http://nevit.blogspot.de/2014/07/arduino-mpu-6050-pitch-roll-with-2.html

When I try to read data separately it works but together it stuck every second (probably reading of gps data) and MPU6050 serial monitor sending FIFO overflow error ..

I tried to lower MPU data rate to 20Hz from 100Hz but it didn't work. I use Arduino UNO.

I am not so much skilled.. Any idea? Is it even possible to do it like this?

Comment: It looks like the instant you have a single character received from the GPS, you will go off and wait until the full mesage is received from it in a blocking collection function where you may be unable to drain the MPU FIFO.  Instead, what you may want to do is collect characters one at a time from the GPS while continuing to monitor the MPU, and only deal with the GPS once you have a complete message from it.

Answer (score 2):

> When I try to read data separately it works, but together it stuck every second (probably reading of gps data) and MPU6050 serial monitor sending FIFO overflow error .

Yes, you have to be careful about the loop structure and "blocking" to "wait" for a new GPS speed report.  SoftwareSerial also blocks everything else during each received character time.

Just check for GPS characters and update the speed if a complete sentence was received, then do "other things" (e.g., use the IMU data).  Here is a [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS) version of your example:

```
#include "NMEAGPS.h"
#include <NeoSWSerial.h>

static const int RXPin = 7, TXPin = 4;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

float gps_speed = 0;

NMEAGPS gps;

// The serial connection to the GPS device
NeoSWSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin( 9600 );
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);
}

void loop(){

  // Read GPS characters and see if a new fix is available
  if (gps.available( ss )) {
    gps_fix fix = gps.read();

    //  A fix is available once per second, but the GPS may not know
    //  the speed value, perhaps because the satellite reception is
    //  poor or the unit is just starting.  Check the valid flag.

    if (fix.valid.speed) {

      // Update the gps_speed.  Other parts of your
      //   program can use it whenever they want.
      gps_speed = fix.speed_kph();
      Serial.println( gps_speed );
    }
  }

}
```

NeoGPS is smaller and faster than other libraries and can be configured to only parse the fields you really use.

Your original sketch uses 6884 bytes program space and 349 bytes of RAM.
The NeoGPS version can be as small as 4802 bytes program space and 150 bytes of RAM. Significant savings!

For the software serial library, I would suggest using AltSoftSerial on pins 8 & 9, if you can move the GPS.  It is much more efficient, and does not disable interrupts for long periods of time: SoftwareSerial will block for ~1ms, and eternity for a 16MHz Arduino.  This is probably interfering with the IMU interrupts.

If you can't move the GPS to pins 8 & 9, you might try another library I maintain, [NeoSWSerial](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoSWSerial).  It is much more efficient than SoftwareSerial, and it works on any two pins.  NeoSWSerial will "play nicer" with the IMU interrupt code, but it can still be affected if the IMU interrupt code takes too long.  NeoSWSerial should not affect the IMU interrupt code.  I used it in the above sketch, along with a debug print.

Answer (score 0):

A guess; Software serial is known for messing with interrupts, in fact I think the rule of thumb is do not use interrupts and software serial.

The MPU code you are using is classic Jeff Rowberg, and uses interrupts.

To be honest, there are things you can do, where an occasional overflow does not cause problems, but that is way too deep to explain here, sorry.

In my case I think I will end up using the arduino to handle the MPU, and attaching it and a GPS to a raspberry pi, and let it merge the two.  You might be able to accomplish something similar with a bigger Arduino if there is one with 2 (or more) uart serial ports, but I do not have experience with that.

If you can speed up the GPS serial rate, give that a try, it actually helps (which is counter intuitive).

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer for you.

GPS keeps on sending data and fill the mcu input buffer . Use listen function and read one software serial at once ..

If you use listen then only one serial port will work at a time and you can swap accordingly .

I was having same problem and It solved my problem

Just open a dummy serial port and when ever you need gps then listen to GPS serial port and do listen to dummy after GPS reading .

Comment: Again, please do not add signatures to your post. I've edited these out. Thanks!